# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS + Logitech MX Mini Keys. How to use keys like play/pause?

Tags: logitech, dell-vostro

How to use keys like play/pause, mute microphone or emoji? Official drivers are only for Windows and Mac.
Im using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and Dell Vostro 5468 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The crucial keyword here is MPRIS, or Media Player Remote Interfacing Specification. If your keyboard *and* the program you want to use it with (for example, a media player) support this specification, the keys should work out of the box. With some media players, you need to activate MPRIS in the settings, add or activate a plugin or something like that.

So, you need to look up whether your keyboard and the program that you want to react to pressing the key support MPRIS.